# Inline assembly errors for Power CPC architecture during compilation with Clang 3.0

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm-clang, powerpc

I am trying to compile the source code that contains ASM optimizations where also a C implementations for Power CPU architecture. The source code was successfully compiled with GCC 4.6.6.1. But failed with Clang 3.0. I am facing below listed errors:

```
1) invalid output constraint '+wr' in asm  
2) unknown register name 'xer' in asm   
3) unknown register name 'r0' in asm
```

I am new with cross compilers. Could some one please help me resolve the issues? I tried to check many solutions online, but I helpless :(

I tried to compile the source files as shown below:

```
C:\Tools\clang.exe -cc1 -emit-llvm  -I C:\MinGW\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include   -o  "Mohan/test/test.o" "../Mohan/test/test.c"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm no clang expert, but wouldn't the default be to generate code for the platform you are running on (which looks like i386)?  Looking at the [docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html), I assume you need to use `-target`.

Comment: Hello Mr David wohlferd,  I tried to compile by clamping `-target powerpc´, except the invalid contraint '+wr'  errors, all other errors are resolved.

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html)  we see that on Powerpc, `wr` means *General purpose register if 64-bit instructions are enabled or NO_REGS*.  I'm not quite sure what `NO_REGS` means, but it sounds like this code is intended for 64bit only.